# Do git tags apply to all branches?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-tag

I'm getting my feet wet with git tagging, but my previous background is in Subversion, where "tags" were really just copies, not "real" tags...

If I add a tag to a git repo, is it applied to all branches or only the current one?

For example, if I currently have these branches (`git branch -v`):

```
* master deadbeef My master head comment
  dev    baddfeed My def head comment
```

And the currently checked out branch is master, as you can see. Now suppose I `git tag -a TAGNAME`, does `TAGNAME` apply only to `deadbeef` (master branch) or to `baddfeed` (dev branch) as well?

e.g., Say I subsequently switch to the dev branch (i.e., not the branch the tag was created on) before checking out the tag:

```
git checkout dev
git checkout TAGNAME
```

Do I then end up with a checkout of `baddfeed` or will the tag checkout (second line) switch me back to the master branch (where the tag was created) and give me a checkout of `deadbeef`?
(Or third option, is my understanding of creating and restoring tags too flawed or too simplistic for the answer to be as simple as one of those two options?)

Also, does the answer to my question change any if I use a lightweight tag (`git tag TAGNAME`) instead of an annotated tag?

Comment: I highly recommend reading: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging & https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html. Everything is in there.

Comment: A tag identifies a single commit. See [The Git Object Model](http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/1_the_git_object_model.html).

Comment: Greg's answer is all you need.  Tags are single commits without context, and they live in a repository-wide namespace.  You don't talk about a given tag being "on" a branch any more than you talk about Linux 3.11 being "on" any branch (obviously it will exist in *any* branch of the kernel!).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's say you are in branch `myBranch`. And you create a tag called `myTag`

```
-----A-----B-----C-----D-----H-------I-----> master
                       \
                        \
                         \---E----F-----G-----> myBranch
                                        |
                                        myTag
```

The tag will be only on the commit object of the `myBranch` branch. I've worked with CVS too, and it tags revisions too, not all branches (but in CVS branches are special tags). I don't think.

If you checkout `myTag`, you will be in the commit `G` of the example. You can't create tags with the same name on differente branches. If you do it, you will move the tag.

There's no difference for an annotated tag related to this.

Note: when checking out tags, you end up with "detached HEAD" mode. Your changes will be lost unless you create another branch starting from the tag checked out.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it very clear. So just to close the loop, if I gave the sequence of commands in my OQ (i.e., `git checkout dev; git checkout TAGNAME`) then I would end up back in the _master_ brach, with the `deadbeef` commit checked out in detached mode (even if that happened to still be head of master, it would be checked out detached); is that correct?

Comment: Techncially, commits added in "detached HEAD" mode are not *lost*: they just have no convenient name, so you have to use the raw SHA-1 ID.  You can paste on a branch name after-the-fact.  It's just a pain to do it that way.  (Also, after a while—the default is 90 days—they will get garbage-collected if they still have no "nice" name.)

Comment: @DaveLillethun Yes. You'll be in master again. Even if the commit is the HEAD, you'll be in the detached HEAD mode.

Comment: @torek You're right. And I agree with you: "It's just a pain to do it that way.". Just in case someone gets here and is curious about how to get the commit ID for these "lost" commits, use `git reflog`.

Comment: But if you created a tag for `A`, then the tag would appear in both `master` and `myBranch` branches. See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088183/do-git-tags-apply-to-all-branches/77957632#77957632

Answer (score 10):

To make it simple:

> If I add a tag to a git repo, is it applied to all branches or only the current one?

In Git, a tag is simply an alias to a commit id. When you add a tag, Git simply maps your tag name (the tag string) to a given commit id. Since the commit id is relevant to a specific branch (or branches when merging) the tag will be relevant only to that branch (and to any it was merged into).

More info can be found here:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging#Creating-Tags

Answer (score 9):

Having read the questions and your comments, I think the basic point that is confusing you here is what it means in git (vs other systems) to be "on a branch".

In git, a `git checkout` operation checks out some particular commit [but see footnote 1].  It also sets the special name `HEAD` so that it refers to that particular commit.  But: there are *two different ways* that `HEAD` can specify a particular commit.  It can be:

- by ID (this is the *not*-usual case), or
- by indirect reference to a branch name (this is the more-usual case).

If you do `git checkout branchname`, git sets up the second, usual case.  If you then `cat .git/refs/HEAD` you will find it contains the literal string `ref:` followed by `refs/heads/branchname` [2].  That's what it means to be "on the branch": you have checked out the commit that the branch-name refers to, but also, `HEAD` is a "symbolic ref".  If you make new changes and commit them, git will make the new commit, then "peel off" the branch label sticky-note and paste it onto the new commit you just added.  That "moves the branch" to the newly added tip, and you're "still on the branch".

On the other hand, if you do `git checkout tagname`, git sets up the first, unusual case.  It does the same if you check out by SHA-1 ID (those `ea56709...` style strings).  In this case, the file for `HEAD` just has the literal SHA-1 ID in it.  In this state, if you make a new commit, it gets added as usual, but there's no sticky-note-changing to move branch labels around.  You're not "on a branch"; `HEAD` is not a "symbolic ref".

As far as the actual tags themselves go, they are merely names for commits.  But wait, isn't that what a branch name is?  Yes!  The difference between a branch name and a tag name is that a branch name is *expected* to move, and git will move it automatically in that "on a branch" case.  A tag name is **not** "expected to move" [3] and will never move automatically.

---

Footnotes:

[1] Just to confuse things (or because git's user interface is "evil", as some would put it :-) ) there are cases when `git checkout` does not alter `HEAD`, specifically when you ask it to check out particular pathnames.

[2] In very old versions of git, instead of `ref: ...` git used a symbolic link.  The target of the link was the branch ID-file, e.g., `refs/heads/master` or whatever, so opening and reading the file got the commit ID, and you had to use `lstat` to detect "on a branch".  This does not work on Windows and precluded "packing" refs (`.git/packed-refs`), hence the change to use `ref:` instead.

[3] The phrases "is expected" and "is not expected" should prompt you to ask: expected *by whom*?  Git itself is OK with git users moving tags, it's the *people using git* (and often, scripts they write) that get confused by this.  So don't move a tag unless you've first checked with other people sharing the repository.

Comment: Wow the best explanation for tags I ever saw, thank you matser

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a git tag will apply to all branches that contain that commit. Git tags are applied to a commit, and all branches that contain that commit will have that git tag. You do not need to apply the git tag to every branch.

Here's an example. If you have tagged the `a` commit, `tag-a` will appear for any branch that contains the `a` commit. (Of course, `tag-b` will not appear for `branch2`, and `tag-c` will not appear for `branch1`.)

```
a---b---> branch1
 \
  --c---> branch2
```

Script to reproduce example:

```bash
git switch -c branch1
echo a > a.txt; git add a.txt; git commit -m "a.txt"
git tag tag-a

git switch -c branch2
echo c > c.txt; git add c.txt; git commit -m "c.txt"
git tag tag-c

git switch branch1
echo b > b.txt; git add b.txt; git commit -m "b.txt"
git tag tag-b

git switch branch1
git log --oneline --graph
* e564800 (HEAD -> branch1, tag: tag-b) b.txt
* 5c82b05 (tag: tag-a) a.txt

git switch branch2
git log --oneline --graph
* 67c3177 (HEAD -> branch2, tag: tag-c) c.txt
* 5c82b05 (tag: tag-a) a.txt
```