# How to know if you have modified the current tag in git

Tags: git

I need to find a way and understand how this works.

When we release a version using git we tag it with a version number. Is there a way to know if the current branch you are working on is still the same as that tag or has been modified (thus that tag is really no longer valid).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you add an example of what you mean?

Comment: I need to build a script that either shows the tag if unmodified or if modified shows the branch

Comment: @Cameron exactly: that is what `git describe --long` is for, as I mention below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`git describe`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe): it will include the number of commits since the last tag.

I use it with the `--long` option, since it always output the long format (the tag, the number of commits and the abbreviated commit name) even when it matches a tag. Instead of just emitting the tag name, it will describe such a commit as `v1.2-0-gdeadbee` (0th commit since tag v1.2 that points at object `deadbee…`.).

> Do you know the command to show the current branch name?

That would be [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

Comment: Thanks Von I was also thinking that maybe if the branch was master to show the tag and anything else just show the branch name. Do you know the command to show the current branch name?

Comment: Last question I promise. The master should only really be using the release version (tag) so this I think is a good option do you agree?

Comment: @Cameron it is indeed a best practice (this is not imposed by git itself though)

Comment: @Cameron to my last point, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18091320/6309 is a good read.